# Building CCminer on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, make, cuda, clang

I recently started to mine some cryptconcurrencys again and I wanted to try Monero (XMR). The CPU miner xmrig works perfectly however I am having problems install a GPU miner.

### What I already did

#### I already installed the graphic drivers for my GTX 1070 (I am using 375.66)

```
itssme@muhbuntu:~$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Jul 26 20:48:30 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 27%   32C    P8     7W / 151W |    653MiB /  8112MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

---

#### I already installed cuda (apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit)

```
itssme@muhbuntu:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

---

#### Cloning ccminer from github

```
https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer.git
```

---

#### Running "./autogen.sh" and "./configure"

```
itssme@muhbuntu:~$ ./autogen.sh 
configure.ac:4: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:6: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'

itssme@muhbuntu:~$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking whether be32dec is declared... no
checking whether le32dec is declared... no
checking whether be32enc is declared... no
checking whether le32enc is declared... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX code... yes
checking whether we can compile XOP code... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX2 code... yes
checking for json_loads in -ljansson... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... yes
checking for EVP_DigestFinal_ex in -lcrypto... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for the version of libcurl... 7.52.1
checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes
checking whether libcurl is usable... yes
checking for curl_free... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating compat/Makefile
config.status: creating compat/jansson/Makefile
config.status: creating cpuminer-config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

---

### Where I fail

#### Running the make command

```
itssme@muhbuntu:~/Documents/ccminer$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer'
Making all in compat
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer/compat'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer/compat'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer/compat'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer/compat'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-crc32.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-crc32.Tpo -c -o ccminer-crc32.o `test -f 'crc32.c' || echo './'`crc32.c
mv -f .deps/ccminer-crc32.Tpo .deps/ccminer-crc32.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-hefty1.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-hefty1.Tpo -c -o ccminer-hefty1.o `test -f 'hefty1.c' || echo './'`hefty1.c
mv -f .deps/ccminer-hefty1.Tpo .deps/ccminer-hefty1.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-ccminer.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-ccminer.Tpo -c -o ccminer-ccminer.o `test -f 'ccminer.cpp' || echo './'`ccminer.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-ccminer.Tpo .deps/ccminer-ccminer.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-util.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-util.Tpo -c -o ccminer-util.o `test -f 'util.cpp' || echo './'`util.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-util.Tpo .deps/ccminer-util.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-log.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-log.Tpo -c -o ccminer-log.o `test -f 'log.c' || echo './'`log.c
mv -f .deps/ccminer-log.Tpo .deps/ccminer-log.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-api.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-api.Tpo -c -o ccminer-api.o `test -f 'api.cpp' || echo './'`api.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-api.Tpo .deps/ccminer-api.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-hashlog.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-hashlog.Tpo -c -o ccminer-hashlog.o `test -f 'hashlog.cpp' || echo './'`hashlog.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-hashlog.Tpo .deps/ccminer-hashlog.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-nvml.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-nvml.Tpo -c -o ccminer-nvml.o `test -f 'nvml.cpp' || echo './'`nvml.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-nvml.Tpo .deps/ccminer-nvml.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-stats.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-stats.Tpo -c -o ccminer-stats.o `test -f 'stats.cpp' || echo './'`stats.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-stats.Tpo .deps/ccminer-stats.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-sysinfos.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-sysinfos.Tpo -c -o ccminer-sysinfos.o `test -f 'sysinfos.cpp' || echo './'`sysinfos.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-sysinfos.Tpo .deps/ccminer-sysinfos.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -fopenmp  -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT ccminer-cuda.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ccminer-cuda.Tpo -c -o ccminer-cuda.o `test -f 'cuda.cpp' || echo './'`cuda.cpp
mv -f .deps/ccminer-cuda.Tpo .deps/ccminer-cuda.Po
nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I.  --ptxas-options="-v" --maxrregcount=128 -o heavy/heavy.o -c heavy/heavy.cu
ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available.
       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.
Makefile:2073: recipe for target 'heavy/heavy.o' failed
make[2]: *** [heavy/heavy.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer'
Makefile:1621: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/itssme/Documents/ccminer'
Makefile:564: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

### The problem

**ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available.
           Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.**

The problem seems to be that CUDA 8.0 doens't support gcc 6. So how can I use clang instead? (I already installed it via apt)

Comment: Did you run the command "nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8"? Also what command did you use to install clang?

Comment: I used `apt install clang-3.8` and
yes I did run `nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8` but it had no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix : open the makefile, search for nvcc (with nano it's CTRL+W, enter "nvcc") and replace it with "nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8", save the makefile and make again.

Answer (score 2):

Using clang-3.8 still left me with linking errors. However, I managed to get ccminer to compile on Ubuntu 17 by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
./configure.sh
```

Edit the following lines in the Makefile:

```
CXX = g++-4.9
NVCC = /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin gcc-4.9
ac_ct_CC = gcc-4.9
ac_ct_CXX = g++-4.9
```

Then finally:

```
make
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to choose your compiler is by passing the appropriate variables to ./configure:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
CC=gcc-4.9 CPP=cpp-4.9 CXX=g++-4.9 ./configure
```

Currently, nvcc doesn't seem to like GCC versions newer than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Editing Makefile and commenting lines:

```
#scrypt/salsa_kernel.o: scrypt/salsa_kernel.cu
#       $(NVCC) $(JANSSON_INCLUDES) -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O3 -lineno -Xcompiler -Wall  -D_FORCE_INLINES -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" -o $@ -c $<

# These kernels are for older devices (SM)

#scrypt/test_kernel.o: scrypt/test_kernel.cu
#       $(NVCC) $(JANSSON_INCLUDES) -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O3 -lineno -Xcompiler -Wall  -D_FORCE_INLINES -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -o $@ -c $<

#scrypt/fermi_kernel.o: scrypt/fermi_kernel.cu
#       $(NVCC) $(JANSSON_INCLUDES) -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O3 -lineno -Xcompiler -Wall  -D_FORCE_INLINES -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" -o $@ -c $<
```

Then run:

```
make
```

It worked for me.